# SignalR - Getting a connection id on server-side during negotiate request

Tags: signalr

SignalR's negotiate calls returns a connection id.  Is there a way to get connection id on server side when negotiate request has been called?

Is there a server side event that I can subscribe to when connection id has been generated?

Answer (score 1):

string connectionID = Context.ConnectionId;

Comment: The Context property returns a HubCallerContext object which provides access to the following information:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PersistentConnection you can override the

```
ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
```

method and get the connectionId value from the IResponse property of the HostContext.

Another way would be to use the DependecyResolver to provide your own implementation of IConnectionIdFactory that raises an event before returning the connectionId string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SignalR Hub, you can listen to the connect event then grab **Context.ConnectionId**. E.g.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    return Clients.All.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs for more.